# Electric baseboard versus heat pump efficiency (btu's/kilowatt-hour or similar measure)

Tags: electricity

I was talking with a friend complaining about his electric baseboard bill, almost \$1000/month during winter, and considering installing a heat pump. But just on basic considerations, I suggested he first carefully research its efficiency *vis-a-vis* electric baseboard. I'd assume the baseboard simply gets $I^2R=IV$, essentially turning all the electric power into heat. So the heat pump can't do any better (and likely somewhat worse). Is that right, or am I missing some not-so-obvious thing?

The not-so-obvious suggests itself becuase the conversion is $1Kwh=3400btu$. But I've seen plenty of air conditioners that do way better than $3400btu's/hour$ using less than a kilowatt. And I'd assume the reverse direction would be similar. But then how can they beat $I^2R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are indeed missing some not-so-obvious thing, as follows:

A heat pump is an air conditioner in reverse: it uses mechanical work to extract heat from a cold source (the outside world) and deposit it into a warm space (your house). Most of the power its compressor motor dissipates in the course of performing this work ends up in the warm space along with whatever heat it manages to extract from the cold source.

The choice of refrigerant used as the working fluid determines the minimum outside temperature the heat pump can work with. as long as the ambient temperature is above that design minimum, the heat pump beats the baseboard system, or any other home heater that uses resistance wire to heat air, for overall efficiency.

For this reason, heat pump retrofits are replacing resistance-wire space heaters all across the country.

Comment: Thanks. In your thermodynamic cycle analysis, I was kind of thinking that the rankine cycle (for heat pump) couldn't outperform the carnot cycle (which I was kind of analogously associating with $I^2R$ heating). But I believe you're saying above that the heat pump isn't a closed cycle -- "along with whatever heat it manages to extract from the cold source" would be the closed part, whereas "power its compressor motor dissipates in the course of performing this work ends up in the warm space" isn't part of a closed cycle. So, without that not-closed part, would heat pump always lose to $I^2R$?

Comment: without the heat pulled from the environment, the heat pump generates nothing but I^2R losses. Here is another way to think of this problem:  let's run the heat pump as an air conditioner for a minute. its job is now to pull heat from a warm space and exhaust it into a hot environment. the hot exhaust consists of both the heat extracted from the warm space but also the power losses in the motor and compressor. so in this case, that "heat work" is thrown away.